# Do dummies ("pacifiers") hinder speech development?

Tags: infant, newborn, pacifier

I have always frowned on the use of dummies, because my mother (who ran a nursery for 25 years) was adamant that they can hinder a child's speech development.

Our new baby is very unsettled and very collicy, and the midwife is recommending using a dummy to help settle him.

So, is there any evidence behind this claim that it hinders speech development? And if so, what is the age that it starts making a difference?

Comment: Our baby was collicy for the first month or so. We would do anything to calm her that seemed harmless. (No Cognac, though.) Giving that virtually every child uses a dummy, I think the small risk that it hinders development is worth taking if it calms her. It'll also help save your nerves.

Comment: Where is the term dummy used for a pacifier? I've never heard that term used as a reference to a pacifier. Is this used in England?

Comment: Yes, it's hard to talk when there is something in your mouth.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini. Yes "dummy" is the normal word in England.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: And Australia.

Comment: Dummy just means 'not the real thing', just like a crash test dummy or a ventriloquist's doll. As for your question, colic will pass, and when it does, you can begin to give your baby the dummy only during nap/sleep times. There's plenty of time until speech begins.

Comment: In the US we also call a pacifier a binky.

Comment: Interestingly, when I was in theater, they advised us to put a cork in our mouths while practicing because it would IMPROVE our articulation. (And that actually worked)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I remembered reading that recent pediatric research in the US has said that pacifiers are OK.  I looked at some recent papers and found these:

- [Pacifiers reduce the risk of SIDS](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/128/5/e1341.full#sec-36) (Sudden Infant Death Syndrome).  That's a pretty strong recommendation for nap-time use.
- [Pacifiers *probably* don't interfere with breast-feeding](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11466098).  There's correlation between pacifier-use and poor breast-feeding, but the suspicion is that trouble breast-feeding leads to more use, rather than the other way around.
- [Pacifiers are a risk-factor for acute otitis media (ear infections)](http://fampra.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/4/233.full).  Pretty weird, I thought.  Other risk factors include not breast-feeding, living with smokers, having siblings, and going to day-care.  The risk increase is pretty small, but they say that if you use a pacifier and your kid gets an infection, you might consider stopping, because the risk increase for repeated infections is greater.
- [Pacifiers may cause some tooth/mouth deformation, but that generally stops when the child discontinues sucking](http://ejo.oxfordjournals.org/content/8/2/127.abstract?ijkey=be6de7e3455f7b13bf22b7474911311e3617cefe&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha).  This paper is the oldest of the bunch by far, and so I wonder if modern pacifiers might not be better, but I couldn't find any newer study.

I would summarize these papers as saying pacifiers are **good for infants below 6 months of age**, **bad for children over 3 years of age**, and **neutral for children aged 6 months to 3 years**.

edit: I realized I didn't actually answer your specific question.  I found no papers at all on the subject of pacifiers and speech development, which implies that the concern is not considered credible by current pediatricians.

Comment: + 1000: Great list of up to date sources, and intelligent analysis of the relative data.

Comment: Simple... dummies are for sleeping only. That's the rule to follow!

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion, not a study, but I suspect the statement is related to awake/play time, not rest and sleep. By 6 months your baby should move past the collic phase and so either no longer require the dummy/pacifier or only need it for sleep.

Answer (score 1):

[LINK to ADA discussion on tooth development](http://www.ada.org/~/media/ADA/Publications/Files/patient_77.pdf?la=en)

So, it seems that use before teeth start to come in is fine. Like thumb-sucking, stopping it early is the way to go.

Also, if thumb-sucking and pacifier use goes beyond the 'norm', then it might be a problem, but is usually not a significant factor  in speech development. [LINK speech path](http://www.speechpathology.com/ask-the-experts/correlation-between-family-size-and-888)